# how can I use AJAX to pass JS variables to the controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, variables

how can I use AJAX to pass JS variables to the controller?

I'm using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.

I need to pass the value of certain JS variable obtained by a JS function to a controller to add it as a record in DB, I'm currently using several datatables to display information, the user selects a row in a datatable and pressing the next button then get the id of the selected rows and add it to a table in the DB as a row and another datatable shown, the thing is I do not want neither to use forms nor that the page is refreshed, and that all information that is presented is loaded at startup in view, I do a "presave" of selection in each step (datatable) without the user knowing.

now I can get the values ​​of the selected rows in the view and present then in a Hidden_field, i need to get the value that hidden_field in the controller

i have read than AJAX can do the work, but i've not worked with ajax before.

some code:

**script.js** (in coffee)

```
leaveAStepCallback =(obj, context) ->
  alert("Leaving step " + context.fromStep + " to go to step " + context.toStep);
  ret=false
  if (context.fromStep==1 and context.toStep==2)
    document.getElementById('selec1').value= fnGetIdsOfSelectedRows fnGetSelected(oTable1), oTable1 #//get selected rows
    ret=true
```

in **some_controller.rb**
need some like:

```
def pre_save
  if params[:step]=='1' #hidden_Field with step number
    @selrow=params[:selec1].to_s.split(',') #selected rows as '1,2,5,7'
    i=0
    while i<@selrow.length
      pr=@selrow.at(i).to_i #selected row number

      addp=PreSaveTable.new #table to record each selected row
      addp.id_row=pr
      addp.save #save as row in table 
      i=i+1
    end

  end

end
```

some help?

Answer (score 1):

> I've not worked with ajax before

Let me explain:

---

[**Asynchronous Javascript & XML**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Ajax requests  are sent with technology like Javascript to send requests to your server out of the typical HTTP request scope. This means you're able to create pseudo "live" functionality -- no refresh

Using ajax is especially simple with [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your_endpoint",
    data: "your_serialized_data",
    success: function(data) {
        //code on success
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //code on error
    }
});
```

---

**Code**

```
#javascript
$(document).on("event", "element", function(e){
    $.ajax({
       url: "controller/action", 
       data: $("hidden_field").val().serialize()
    });
});

#controller
def pre_save
  if params[:step] == '1' #hidden_Field with step number
    @selrow = params[:selec1].to_s.split(',') #selected rows as '1,2,5,7'
    i=0
    while i < @selrow.length
      pr=@selrow.at(i).to_i #selected row number

      addp=PreSaveTable.new #table to record each selected row
      addp.id_row=pr
      addp.save #save as row in table 
      i=i+1
    end

    respond_to do |format| 
       format.html 
       format.js #-> loads views/controller/pre_save.js.erb
    end

end

#app/views/controller/pre_save.js.erb
alert("Presave Complete!");
```